# C++ on Android missing std::map:at

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, stl, cocos2d-x

I am trying to compile my cocos2d-x project for android, but it I get the error:

> jni/../../Classes/Utility.cpp:359:47: error: 'class
>   std::map,
>   std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >' has no member named
>   'at' make: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/**/**/Classes/Utility.o]
>   Error 1

I have set `APP_STL := stlport_static` in `Application.mk` (not `Android.mk`), I even have set the eclipse include path `{android-ndk-r9}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport`. But still nothing, any ideas? or is that method just not included in this version of c++?

**UPDATE**

I am using `stlport_static`, which is defined as follows (as static library):

> I.3. STLport runtime:
>
> This is a port of STLport (http://www.stlport.org) that can be used on
>   Android. It will provide you with a complete set of C++ standard
>   library headers, with RTTI and exception handling support.
>
> That's because the library embeds its own copy of GAbi++.

My cocos2d-x version is 2.1rc0-x-2.1.4

Comment: This method requires C++11 support. It could be that your compiler doesn't have it, or that you need to explicitly switch it on.

Comment: Which makes me wonder what compiler version you are using...

Comment: and how you invoke the compiler (what the command line looks like)...

Comment: please see my update for more information about the c++ version